# how to make switch execute 2 cases

Tags: linux, bash, shell, switch-statement

how to make switch execute 2 cases?

I tried with the following code, but it execute only the first case

```
#!/bin/sh
action="titi"

case "$action" in
    toto|titi)
    echo "1_$action"
    ;;
    tata|titi)
    echo "2_$action"
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: What you want is called "fall through". Please have a look at : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12010686/case-statement-fallthrough

Comment: What is the expected result and what you got? Do you expect `1_titi` and `2_titi` together ?

Comment: @VoidPointer exactelly I expected 1_titi and 2_titi together

Comment: @josay thank you for the link. I will put the new code as an answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `case` statement in bash executes the commands in the `COMMAND-LIST` for the first match only.

However, In `bash version 4` or later introduced the `;&` terminator. The `;;&` operator is like `;;`, except the case statement doesn't terminate after executing the associated list - Bash just continues testing the next pattern as though the previous pattern didn't match. Using these terminators, a case statement can be configured to test against all patterns, or to share code between blocks, for example.

**Reference:** Excerpt taken from http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/case

So if you have `bash v 4 or later` this would give your desired result:

```
#!/bin/sh
action="titi"

case "$action" in
    toto|titi)
    echo "1_$action"
    ;;&
    tata|titi)
    echo "2_$action"
    ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe consider `titi` a default value to execute if no pattern is matched

```
#!/bin/sh
action="titi"

case "$action" in
    toto)
    echo "1_$action"
    ;;
    tata)
    echo "2_$action"
    ;;
    *)
    echo "1_$action"
    echo "2_$action"
esac
```

Comment: It works for me but I had to add some `"` around `toto` and `tata`

Answer (score 1):

based on **@josay** comment, this is called "fall through" and could be done with bash script by using `;;&` instead of `;;` in the first case. But the "fall through" works only if the bash version is 4.0 or later

Following, Source code updated with the "fall through"

```
#!/bin/sh
action="$1"

case "$action" in
    toto|titi)
    echo "1_$action"
    ;;&
    tata|titi)
    echo "2_$action"
    ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `if` twice and it matches twice.

```
if [ "$action" = 'toto' -o "$action" = 'titi' ]; then
    echo "1_$action"
fi
if [ "$action" = 'tata' -o "$action" = 'titi' ]; then
    echo "2_$action"
fi
```

If you need to use `case`, how about using `function`

```
function f1
{
    echo "1_$action"
}

function f2
{
    echo "2_$action"
}

case "$action" in
    titi)
    f1
    f2
    ;;
    toto)
    f1
    ;;
    tata)
    f2
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: I want to use switch statement and not if