# Why is this simple bash script not working? getopts

Tags: bash, exit, getopts

I don't get why this won't work as it's really simple.

```
#!/bin/bash
type='A'

while getopts "t:" OPTION
do
  case $OPTION in
    t)
       echo "The value of -t is $OPTARG"
       type=$OPTARG
       exit
       ;;
    \?)
       echo "Used for the help menu"
       exit
        ;;
  esac
done
echo $type
```

Output I get:

```
root@w:/etc/scripts# ./dns_add_record -t test  
The value of -t is test  
root@w:/etc/scripts# ./dns_add_record  
A
```

Expected output:

```
root@w:/etc/scripts# ./dns_add_record -t test  
The value of -t is test  
test
```

Can someone figure out what is wrong? It's probably something stupid, but I can't get this working the way I want it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`exit` exits from the shell script.

Remove it from the `-t` case, it only makes sense for help.

---

Adding `set -x` to your script gives this trace:

```
+ type=A
+ getopts t: OPTION
+ case $OPTION in
+ echo 'The value of -t is 3'
The value of -t is 3
+ type=3
+ exit
```

Comment: Wow... Used to java, so figured you needed it at the end of a case. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know why you've thought that, there's nothing similar in Java.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I think OP is referring to [fall through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562253/switch-case-with-fallthrough).