# Bash script with user prompt

Tags: bash, shell

I am very new to bash scripting. I am trying to create a script which creates a local txt file that is treated as a database. The commands the user can use is: quit, add, delete, printdb. How would I create a user prompt? If the user inputs 
quit how would I set up the quit function to quit the script and how would I pass the user input into the function?

I have done:

```
#!/bin/bash
func () {
echo -n "% "
read answer
}
if [ $answer != "quit" ] && [ $answer != "setdb" ] && [ $answer != "add" ] && [ $answer != "delete" ] && [
$answer != "printdb" ]
then
 echo "Unrecognised command"
 func
else
 echo -n "%"
fi



#quit () {}

#setdb (){}

#add () {}

#delete () {}

#printdb () []
```

But it does not recognize if the commands are not valid.

Comment: You really should read a tutorial. If you have already worked on a script, post it in your question. Regards

Comment: I posted my work so far. Apologies.

Comment: You should use a `switch` instead of `if`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562253/switch-case-with-fallthrough . Regards

Comment: and in shell scripting, `switch` statements are expressed as `case ${answer} in quit ) exit 0 ;; setdb ) set DB=$1 ;; * ) echo Unknown option provided $* ;; esac`. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This shows how you can use `read` and `case` to read input.

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
      echo -n "Enter command."
      read -r m
      case $m in
      quit) exit 0 ;; # exit without error
      add) echo "New line" >> printdb.txt ;; # add new line
      delete) sed -i '$d' printdb.txt ;; # delete last line
      printdb) cat printdb.txt ;; # show file
      *) echo "ERROR:Unknown command".; exit 1 ;; # handle invalid command
      esac
done
```

References:

0. [`read` manual page](https://ss64.com/bash/read.html)
1. [Prompt user for input with `read`.](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/bash/read.htm)
2. [How to program responses from `read` with `case`.](https://linuxize.com/post/bash-case-statement/)
3. [How to delete a line from a file by line number with `sed`.](https://www.folkstalk.com/2013/03/sed-remove-lines-file-unix-examples.html)
4. [Tool for getting suggestions while debugging your bash code.](https://www.shellcheck.net/)