# Jumping lines in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, sh

what would goto, translate to in bash script

---

This is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
read distro </etc/issue
echo $distro
if [[ "$distro" = "Debian GNU/Linux bookworm/sid n l" ]];
then
    goto Debian:
elif [[ "$distro" = "Ubuntu GNU/Linux bookworm/sid n l" ]];
then
    goto Ubuntu:
elif [[ "$distro" = "kali GNU/Linux bookworm/sid n l" ]];
then
    goto Kali:
elif [[ "$distro" = "Arch GNU/Linux bookworm/sid n l" ]];
then
    goto Arch:
else
    echo No suported OS detected some thing may not work
fi

Debian:
echo using Debian
sleep 5
exit

Ubuntu:
echo using Ubuntu
sleep 5
exit

Kali:
echo using kali
sleep 5
exit

Arch:
echo using Arch
sleep 5
exit
```

---

Its a really simple code and I don't even know if the way I'm checking the Linux distro will work

I have tried with the Goto function from a batch from windows but it wont work on Linux, how would i jump form line to line

Comment: You could define functions and call those if needed. Also use `elif` so you don't need the 'goto check4'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using a [Switch-Case statement with fall-through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562253/switch-case-with-fallthrough).

All the 'handlers' can be defined in a function that will be called from the switch:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

handleDebian() {
    echo "Using Debian"
}

handleUbuntu() {
    echo "Using Ubuntu"
}

handleKali() {
    echo "Using Kali"
}

handleArch() {
    echo "Using Arch"
}

handleUnknown() {
   echo "No suported OS detected some thing may not work"
}

read distro </etc/issue
case "${distro}" in
    *Debian*)   handleDebian() ;;
    *Ubuntu*)   handleUbuntu() ;;
    *kali*)     handleKali() ;;
    *Arch*)     handleArch() ;;
    *)          handleUnkown() ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case I'd opt for a more compact `case` statement, eg:

```
read distro </etc/issue
echo $distro

case "${distro}" in
    *Debian*)    echo "Debian" ;;
    *Ubuntu*)    echo "Ubuntu" ;;
    *kali*)      echo "kali"   ;;
    *Arch*)      echo "Arch"   ;;
    *)           echo "No suported OS detected some thing may not work";;
esac

sleep 5
```